# JQuery function disables the rest of the option list

Tags: jquery

I am stuck at the following point:

I have got an option list, based on a plain html list. I want to make this list able to select more than on option. I wrote a function that shall do that. Now, my problem is if this js function called, the function disabled a particular number of entries.

Example: When there are more than 5 options in a list and 5 options has been selected, the rest of the options gets disabled.

css

```
    <style>
        ul li{list-style:none; float:left; margin-right:20px; cursor:pointer}
        ul li p.active{text-decoration:underline}
    </style>
```

js

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            var countLi = 5;
            //Checkboxes
            $("#chk>li>p").click(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                    countLi -= 1;
                    if ($("#chkResult").val() != "") {
                        $("#chkResult").val($("#chkResult").val().replace("," + $(this).html(), ""));
                        $("#chkResult").val($("#chkResult").val().replace($(this).html() + ",", ""));
                        $("#chkResult").val($("#chkResult").val().replace($(this).html(), ""));
                    }
                    else {
                        countLi += 1;
                    }

                    if (count == 0) {
                        $("#chk>li>p").each(function () {
                            if (!($(this).hasClass("active"))) {
                                $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {

                        $("#chk>li>p").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ($("#chkResult").val() == "") {
                        $("#chkResult").val($(this).html());
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#chkResult").val($("#chkResult").val() + "," + $(this).html());
                    }
                }

                $(this).toggleClass("active");
            });
        });

    </script>
```

html

```
    <ul id="chk">
            <li><p>One</p></li>
            <li><p>Two</p></li>
            <li><p>Three</p></li>
            <li><p>Four</p></li>
            <li><p>Five</p></li>
            <li><p>Six</p></li>
            <li><p>Seven</p></li>
            <li><p>Eight</p></li>
            <li><p>Nine</p></li>
            <li><p>Ten</p></li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <input id="chkResult" type="text"  style="width:500px;"/>
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: hello ,Question TITLE should be short not LONG! :)

Comment: actually, we want that, when 5 list items are being active then rest of the list items should be desabled.

Comment: You don't *disable* a `p`!

Comment: ok, then how it is possible.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jquery [`:lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector, like :

```
 $('#chk>li>p.active:lt(5)')
```

This automatically narrows the selector's returned set to the first `n` matches.